# Here is a good one I created a function that generates images with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why is it not using the Math.Random I put in there. Thanks in advance.

```
    $(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myFakeChannelData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: changeChannel
    });
});

function changeChannel(xml) {
    $('#layer').fadeOut(1000);
var $limit = 4;
    $(xml).find("Channel").each(function($limit) {  
    var $channel = $(this);
    var image = $channel.attr('image');
    $("#click").click(function () {
    $(".layer-container").empty();
        $(".layer-container").append('<div class="layer1">' + 
    '<img class="" alt=""   src="' + image + '" />' +  '</div></div>');
    $(".layer-container").append('<div class="layer2">' + '<img     class=""            alt=""  src="' + image + '" />' +  '</div></div>');
     $(".layer-container").append('<div class="layer3">' + '<img class="" alt=""    src="' + image + '" />' +  '</div></div>');
    $(".Channel").fadeIn(1000);
    var random = Math.floor(limit * Math.random());
    var myNewChannel = remix(random);
    myNewChannel(random);
    });
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'not using' it? What is the value of `randon` after the line `var random = Math.floor(limit * Math.random());`?

Comment: Well it is not working even though the code seems fine to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to "limit" in that expression, but it should be "$limit".

```
 var random = Math.floor($limit * Math.random());
```

It was probably always coming out zero, since the undefined "limit" would be cast to zero for the multiplication.

Comment: Ok I changed that and it didn't work. It is only getting the first child node in the XML and that's it.

Comment: What do you mean, "only getting the first child node"?  Do you mean the "click" handler is only being bound to one?  If so, that's because you've told it to search by "id" value ("#click"), and there can be only one element on the page with that "id".  If you've got multiple buttons whose "id" is "click", that's a problem and it won't work. Give them a class instead and use ".click" instead of "#click".

Comment: Yeah great point I did have two Click ids. However, I meant when the images are displayed they are all the same. There are several images in the XML file so they should be Randomly rotating when I click the button. I am telling it to randomize by the "image" attribute in the channels XML file.

Comment: But you only call "Math.random()" inside that "click" event handler. Perhaps you haven't posted enough code.